# Laravel upload form returning json

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, upload

i'm still beginner in laravel and stuck with that upload ajax form : it's still sending a json response displayed in the browser instead of staying on the current page as i expect.
I just want to get a json response i could use on current page.

**Here is my view**

```
<form action="/Project/UploadDocumentProject" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post"  id ="form0">

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <input id="ProjectID" name="ProjectID" type="hidden" value="{{$Project->id}}">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="DocumentFile" id="DocumentFile" class="form-control" type="file" >
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <button id ="test" class="btn btn-success upload-image" type="submit">Upload</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

**Here is my ajax request**

```
$('#form0').on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).ajaxForm(options);

    var options = { 
        complete: function(response) 
        {
            if($.isEmptyObject(response.responseJSON.error)){
                $("input[name='DocumentFile']").val('');
                alert('Image Upload Successfully.');
            }else{
                printErrorMsg(response.responseJSON.error);
            }
        }
    };
```

});

**Here is my controller**

```
public function UploadDocumentProject (Request $Request)
{
    $ProjectID=$Request->get('ProjectID');
    $filename = $Request->DocumentFile->getClientOriginalName();

    $Request->DocumentFile->storeAs('/public/projects/'.$ProjectID.'/files',$filename);

    return response()->json(['success'=>'done']);

}
```

**Here is my route**

```
Route::post('/Project/UploadDocumentProject','ProjectController@UploadDocumentProject');
```

I have already tried to specify data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" in my form, but then request does not take file input into account even when specifying data field in my ajax request. 
Could anyone help me ?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally did find how to make a proper ajax file form

Here is how I did it

**View**

```
<form action="{{ route('Project/UploadDocumentProject') }}"  method="post" id ="form0" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input id="ProjectID" name="ProjectID" type="hidden" value="{{$Project->id}}">



        <div class="form-group">
          <input name="fileAjax" id="fileAjax" class="form-control" type="file">test</textarea>  
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button id ="test" class="btn btn-success upload-image" type="submit" >Upload</button>
        </div>


</form>
```

**Ajax Request**

```
var files;


                 $('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);


                 function prepareUpload(event)
                 {
                    files = event.target.files;
                  }
                  $("#form0").submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var form = $("#form0");
                    var data = new FormData();

                    $.each(files, function(key, value)
                       {
                            data.append(key, value);
                        });

                    var $ProjectID = $('#ProjectID').val();

                     data.append('ProjectID', $ProjectID);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: form.attr('action'),
                        data: data,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        },


                        success: function (data) {
                            //some code here...
                        }
                    });
                });
```

**Controller**

```
 public function UploadDocumentProject (Request $Request) {
$path = $Request->file('0')->store('document');
$filename = $Request->file('0')->getClientOriginalName();
$Request->file('0')->storeAs('/public/projects/files',$filename);

  //some code here...

return Response::json(array('var1'=>$val1 ,...));

}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('Project/UploadDocumentProject', ['as'=>'Project/UploadDocumentProject','uses'=>'ProjectController@UploadDocumentProject']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `options` before you use it `.ajaxForm(options)`.
And I would configure it directly after loading instead of in the submit-Handler

Reworked JS Code:

```
$.ready(function(){
    var options = { 
        complete: function(response)
        {
            if($.isEmptyObject(response.responseJSON.error)){
                $("input[name='DocumentFile']").val('');
                alert('Image Upload Successfully.');
            }else{
                printErrorMsg(response.responseJSON.error);
            }
        }
    };
    $(this).ajaxForm(options);
}};
```

If tested it without a target backend php application - But request including a File was sent. So if you face additional problems just let me know

Comment: Thanks for help ! But seems like i'm getting back to my problem : request is sent to server but without the file info...

Comment: ok then we need to step into debugging :-)
are you really sure the file is sent to the server? (have you checked your browser devtools - especially the network tab?)
if you are sure please change your php code according to https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#file-uploads (i assume you are using the latest laravel version) - `$path = $Request->file('DocumentFile')->store('document');` `echo $path`;

Comment: Actually it is not. It sends a request but with the Project ID input but without the file input. So server sends back a 500 response specifying that i'm calling functions on null.

Comment: Thats bad :-/ which browser are you using? it should support `XMLHttpRequest` https://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2

Comment: Chrome 69 and firefox 62 both up to date :/

Comment: sorry, now I have no additional idea what the problem could be- for me (chrome 69) it's working http://jsfiddle.net/n2gtrsyw/ when the request is sent out, I see a quite big `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` is `multipart/form-data;` - also the form data is properly filled `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="DocumentFile"; filename="image.png"
`

Comment: Nice ! seems to work outside when I include it in partial ! But still the json response is printed in the browser when I just would like it to display an alert message. Any idea about this one ?

Comment: maybe check what `response` contains in the complete callback - `console.log(response)`

Comment: I tried to do so but seems like browser is stuck on my Project/UploadDocumentProject url and display the response as an array and does not stay on the form view as expected. so including console.log(response) in my ajax options does not let me access the complete callback. Seems like I miss something obvious